# Detect window.onfocus with a full screen flash control?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a flash object that takes up the whole browser on my website.  I am trying to detect if the browser is in focus or not.  What is the best way to do this?  Using onfocus / onblur works in FireFox, but not in IE6 or IE7.

```
window.onblur = function() {
  document.title = "NOT focused";
}
window.onfocus = function() {
  document.title = "focused"
}
```

If I remove the flash object, it looks like this will work in IE6/7 also, but that is not an option for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS3 you can add an event listener to the stage:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, windowNotActiveCallback);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, windowActiveCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = function(){document.title = "focused";}
    document.onfocusout = function(){document.title = "NOT focused";}
} else {
    window.onfocus = function(){document.title = "focused";}
    window.onblur = function(){document.title = "NOT focused";}
}
```

Comment: This still had a few misfires when going in and out of tabs, but was definitely better than what I had!